# Get JSONs from directory inside server of NodeJS+ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

I need simple code to load ALL json files from one directory to some variable.
For example i have folder "public/data" with 2 JSON files:

public/data/a8c6.JSON

```
{
    "nr": "a8c6",
    "1": {
            "id": 1
    },
    "2": {
            "id": 2
    }
}
```

public/data/b8m6.JSON

```
{
    "nr": "b8m6",
    "1": {
            "id": 3
    },
    "2": {
            "id": 4
    }
}
```

And i need to have variable "n" in server of nodejs to be like:

```
n['a8c6'] = {"nr":"a8c6", "1":{"id": 1}, "2":{"id": 2}}
n['b8m6'] = {"nr":"b8m6", "1":{"id": 3}, "2":{"id": 4}}

> n['b8m6'][1]['id']
< 3
```

I'm using nodejs and express. I really want the code to be simple, not 50 unnecessary lines.

(Ofc they aren't real files, but i will change code to something i have.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i guess i have it. Need to test it yet.

```
const fs = require('fs')
var n = []
fs.readdir(__dirname+'/public/data/', function (e, files) {
    if (e) throw e;
    files.forEach(function (file) {
        let data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/public/data/'+file, 'utf8'))
        n[data['nr']] = data
    })
})
```